# Documentation multiline syntax

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, documentation

Well, I know syntax section in Documentation is said to contain just small (presumably, one-line) snippets of code.

But there are *quite a few languages that are said to contain line breaks and indentation inside its grammar*.

For example, Ruby language contains `\n` in its grammar. Semicolon is allowed but redundant. You can write either

```
class A; end
```

... which is a bad style or

```
class A
end
```

... which is a good one and supposed to be common, or even *best practice*.

There is a proposed change I can't accept because it seems not to be formatted properly

[image: Three lines syntax section]

Just because of these awful `<hr>`-s, that make me think **each line of this snippet is a separate example**, despite the fact that it is **one little example**.

I tried in vain to achieve desired result but failed miserably. I read about [nesting code within a list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown) but it didn't help.

How to format multiline code snippet properly?

---

Edit:

I found out that indentation does not work at all

```
 - 
      class Hello
        # description goes here
      end
 - 'goodbye'
```

produces

[image: Indentation does not work]

whereas ```` ``` ```` adds one extra line after:

````
 - ```ruby
   class Hello
     # description goes here
   end
   ```
 - 'goodbye'
````

produces

[image: Extra line]

Comment: What if you put that last set of triple-ticks on the same line as `end`?

Comment: @Frank and others, how on Earth my question is a duplicate if it had been asked 4 months earlier than question that has been marked as "original"?

Comment: I admit that another question might be better and more comprehensive, but anyway, this wasn't asked accidentally or without sufficient amount of searching through the website having been done

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `&nbsp;`:

```
- class Hello  
&nbsp; # description goes here  
end

- 'goodbye'
```

Will result in:

[image: SyntaxHello1]

You can use as many instances of `&nbsp;` as you like to achieve different levels of indenting:

[image: SyntaxHello2]