# Multi-line formatting in Syntax section of Documentation

Tags: support, documentation, syntax-section

I've started browsing the Documentation for some of my favourite tags and am looking to contribute. As a soft start to ease myself in, I came across the [GROUP BY](//stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/627/group-by) topic within the [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag, which said it was missing a Syntax section.

Thinking this would be an easy and helpful thing to include, I took the MSDN syntax for the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
-- Syntax for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database   
-- ISO-Compliant Syntax  

GROUP BY {
      column-expression  
    | ROLLUP ( <group_by_expression> [ ,...n ] )  
    | CUBE ( <cgroup_by_expression> [ ,...n ] )  
    | GROUPING SETS ( <grouping set> [ ,...n ]  )  
    | () --calculates the grand total 
} [ ,...n ] 

<group_by_expression> ::=  
      column-expression  
    | ( column-expression [ ,...n ] )    

<grouping_set> ::=  
      () --calculates the grand total  
    | <grouping_set_item>  
    | ( <grouping_set_item> [ ,...n ] )  

<grouping_set_item> ::=  
      <group_by_expression>  
    | ROLLUP ( <group_by_expression> [ ,...n ] )  
    | CUBE ( <group_by_expression> [ ,...n ] )  


-- For backward compatibility only.
-- Non-ISO-Compliant Syntax for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database 

GROUP BY 
      [ ALL ] column-expression [ ,...n ] 
    | column-expression [ ,...n ] [ WITH { CUBE | ROLLUP } ]

-- Syntax for Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Parallel Data Warehouse  

GROUP BY {
      column-name [ WITH (DISTRIBUTED_AGG) ]  
    | column-expression
} [ ,...n ]
```

However, I was totally unable to get this multi-line text to appear as above when entered into the Syntax section of this Topic. I found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330296/documentation-multiline-syntax) and was able to get the code snippet to appear in the right format in my preview, but when attempting to submit my edit, I received the error:

`Syntax must be formatted as a list of one-liners`

As per the question linked above, I did begin my text with a bulleted list marker (as per the [SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/222/select#t=201612091141411100921) Topic), but it still won't be accepted. I also tried having multiple bullet point markers, but this still didn't work and I didn't want to submit with a bullet point marker on every single line as this looked horrible in the preview.

Having read up a bit more on the intended purpose of the Syntax section (including the "Listing Syntax" yellow help box to the right when editing), it seems that perhaps this section is not intended to contain a syntax definition in the same way as pages on MSDN do, but rather is for something else  - "removing duplication from examples" is given as the main reason it seems.

What exactly is meant by this?

Can someone provide an example of what **is** meant to go in the Syntax section of a Topic?

If the intention is not to hold MSDN-esque Syntax definitions, should I be doing something about Topics where this is what has been provided (for example, the [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) Topic on [SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/222/select#t=201612091141411100921) has a multi-line syntax displayed in a similar way to what I have tried to achieve, although I have not used their exact approach as the `GROUP BY` syntax would benefit from indentation, which doesn't appear to be possible).

**Edit:**

Following discussion in the comments, as an example, let's just assume that I want to get the following text into the Syntax section (putting aside the fact that it's lifted from the MSDN page):

```
GROUP BY {
      column-expression  
    | ROLLUP ( <group_by_expression> [ ,...n ] )  
    | CUBE ( <cgroup_by_expression> [ ,...n ] )  
    | GROUPING SETS ( <grouping set> [ ,...n ]  )  
    | () --calculates the grand total 
} [ ,...n ]
```

If I paste this text into the editor verbatim, I get the whole thing as a single line of text:

[image: SyntaxFormatting1]

I can get it split onto multiple lines by adding newlines (which looks pretty ugly in the editor:

[image: SyntaxFormatting2]

However, this will not submit due to the `Syntax must be formatted as a list of one-liners` warning.

If I add a bullet to the first line, it puts loads of space between the first and second lines:

[image: SyntaxFormatting3]

And if I try to remove the empty line, it puts the second line back onto the end of the first line:

[image: SyntaxFormatting4]

So I don't see a way to cleanly present multi-line syntax definitions, let alone include indenting as well.

**Edit 2:**

As suggested by [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank), you can get the preview to look exactly as you wish by using a double space at the end of each line and a number of `&nbsp;` to indent:

[image: SyntaxFormatting5]

However, once again this will not submit due to the `Syntax must be formatted as a list of one-liners` warning.

I tried exactly as [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank) suggested, with just a single `&nbsp;` on each line I wanted to indent (even though this is not the exact formatting I'd like), but this also would not submit:

[image: SyntaxFormatting9]

I've also tried using `<pre>` and this seems to add an unwanted blank line which I cannot get rid of:

[image: SyntaxFormatting6]

Then I thought I'd cracked it, as adding four spaces to the start of each subsequent line (like when adding a code block in a normal Q or A post) seemed to do the trick:

[image: SyntaxFormatting7]

However, this also will not submit due to the `Syntax must be formatted as a list of one-liners` warning.

Comment: You should not be copying and pasting things from MSDN into Documentation anyway...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan fair enough, so is there some more detailed guidance anywhere (with examples) as to how the Syntax section should be completed? Let's say I had my own multi-line syntax definition which wasn't taken directly from MSDN - how would I (or even should I) get that to display correctly?

Comment: Oh, I have no idea. I just wanted to make sure you (and anyone else coming to this topic later) don't think it's okay to copy and paste information from another site. I would say that the Syntax section was meant to be single-line, like [Promises in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises#t=201612091554286045733&a=syntax), but you can see examples of it in SQL, like the [CASE syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/456/case#t=20161209155541107372&a=syntax), so I'd think each version of `GROUP BY` should be its own "line".

Comment: Understood about copy/pasting information from elsewhere, part of me was expecting my edit to be rejected for that reason anyway, then I got hooked on trying to get it to display correctly. I think my main issue here is that there are loads of legitimate examples where Syntax cannot easily be defined on a single line and without the ability to indent different lines of the definition differently - I believe a `GROUP BY` in SQL is an example of this. I was trying to understand whether this formatting issue is my real problem, or whether I do not understand the purpose of the Syntax section.

Comment: I managed to get around the multiline thing a little bit by adding trailing spaces to bullet items and a lot of indentation on successive lines here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/849/data-table#t=201612091832352886194 I think they had in mind each Docs topic being about a single function and the Syntax section being the function's docstring (like python has), which isn't very useful for any of the Docs I've looked at.

Comment: @Frank yes, that's one approach I've seen elsewhere, but having separate bullet points for each line looks terrible when you're trying to present a genuinely multi-line syntax, plus it doesn't look like you were able to actually cause any indentation to be displayed when it's rendered on the page, which is something else that makes more complex syntax statements a lot easier to read.

Comment: @3N1GM4 I'm not sure I follow re bullets. The displayed result has zero bullets; those are just required for the person writing the Syntax section. Yeah, I wasn't trying to indent and don't know if it's possible. My usage was pretty basic.

Comment: @Frank I mean that each time you use a bullet in your markdown, the rendered output is spaced, so adjacent rows do not sit tight to each other. If you had a syntax expression of even half a dozen lines, this starts to look really messy.

Comment: I'll edit my question to provide some more examples of the things I'm unable to do which I think are necessary to properly describe syntax.

Comment: Google told me about `&nbsp;` which seems to "work": http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/627/group-by#t=201612091859299311565

Comment: Ah, I see, it seems that &nbsp; works, but only if the preceding line ends with two spaces? If I remove the spaces from the end of the preceding line, the line break is lost?

Comment: Yeah, I think that the two spaces are needed for it being multiline and in addition, the nbsp is needed for lines with indentation. (My first link didn't have indentation and so no nbsp.) Strangely, I wasn't able to view the source for my draft (second link) and so had to discard it and start over.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan isn't it *extremely reasonable* to copy the "syntax" from existing documentation (along with a link to it, for when/if it changes)? The alternative is to type by hand, arriving at the same thing, or to type by hand and get it wrong. Surely?

Comment: @BillWoodger As long as the license is compatible with the CC-by-SA license Documentation uses, and sufficient attribution is made. There was no indication of such care being taken in this case.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it's the documentation feature. Is the documentation supposed to reference, explicitly, the document defining the syntax of a statement? In limited examples, I'll be able to write the syntax without reference to a document. It will be identical to what is in the document. Should I therefore include a reference to the document? Isn't there an implication (assuming it is correct) that the determinant place for the syntax is the documentation of the product? Just seems a curious expenditure of effort when it is 100% implied.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan obviously different in a case where someone just pastes text from the same documentation, without attribution, but the syntax itself?

Comment: @BillWoodger My comments were specific to this case, but I don't think it is 100% implied that the "determinant place for syntax is the documentation", considering the purpose of Stack Overflow Documentation was to document those places where the existing documentation is poor or incomplete.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan well, syntax can't be invented. Obviously if it is not documented at all, the issue of copying it without accreditation is moot. If I type up some syntax from memory, it will be either logically or identically the same, or it will be wrong. Pasting it seems better, I'm unconvinced about the need to specifically accredit syntax. But, hey, it's not the end of the world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to get the indenting ([submitted as an actual edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/114848?filter-tags=sql), since I wasn't sure where else to test):

```
- GROUP BY {  
&nbsp;  column-expression  
&nbsp;    | ROLLUP ( <group_by_expression> [ ,...n ] )  
&nbsp;    | CUBE ( <cgroup_by_expression> [ ,...n ] )  
&nbsp;    | GROUPING SETS ( [ ,...n ] )  
&nbsp;    | () --calculates the grand total  
} [ ,...n ]
- <group_by_expression> ::=  
&nbsp;    column-expression  
&nbsp;    | ( column-expression [ ,...n ] )
```

There are two trailing spaces at the end of every non-terminal line; and a `&nbsp;` at the start of every line that needs indentation.

---

> Can someone provide an example of what **is** meant to go in the Syntax section of a Topic?

I had the same question as the OP. We heard more [from Jon Ericson in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34519900#34519900):

> [T]he idea is that you'll use it to cover trivial variations that don't belong in a full example. [...] I think of the Syntax section as something like the Synopsis section of a man page:
>
> ```
> SYNOPSIS 
> mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target 
> mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
> ```

This makes it somewhat analogous to / redundant with the Remarks section.

Comment: Can we only get one level of indenting this way? What if I wanted to have he `column-expression` line indented a could of extra spaces?

Comment: Huh, trying to figure that out (deeper indentation), but nothing so far.

Comment: @3N1GM4 I added a way to get further indenting. After looking into it, I think SO should use `<pre>` blocks in the Syntax section by default / in the background instead of second-guessing the whitespace we include. I'm not really knowledgeable about html or what SO has in mind for this section, though.

Comment: Ah, I understand now, the two spaces at the end of the line give us the newline and the `&nbsp;` gives us the indentation. I've been able to exactly reproduce the layout I was after by using 6x `&nbsp;` on the second line and 8x `&nbsp;` on the other indented lines. Will have a play with `<pre>` as well though, as that looks like a better solution.

Comment: Ok, problem is, if I use the `&nbsp;` approach, the edit won't submit, due to the good 'ol `Syntax must be formatted as a list of one-liners` warning. I also haven't been able to get `<pre>` to work either - if I place the opening tag after the bullet and before my text (with the closing tag at the end of my text), it again pushes an extra line between my first and second lines. :(

Comment: @3N1GM4 Ah, darn, you're right. I hadn't been testing by submitting changes, but I see the same thing. Gonna take that part back out of the answer.

Comment: Have updated question again with details of my attempts with the `&nbsp;` and `<pre>` approaches - both can result in something which looks right in preview, but neither will submit successfully.

Comment: @3N1GM4 The (single) nbsp way went through. You can see my changes on the page itself now.

Comment: Unfortunately even the original `&nbsp;` approach you've left in your answer will not submit, so we've still not got a solution. I'd be curious as to why the markdown available has been restricted like this, instead of just letting us use full markdown like in examples. I presume it's to do with this intention that Syntax entries are short, one-line definitions of usage? Seems this is clearly not appropriate for some languages/technologies (including SQL I would suggest!).

Comment: @3N1GM4 There's a Docs chatroom we could use to discuss further and not fill up all the space with comments here. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117558/documentation-public-beta

Comment: that's really odd - see my latest update for what I thought was exactly the same as your suggestion, which is definitely failing to submit. Must be something different between yours and mine, just trying to spot it...

Comment: So I got this working (I had a superfluous space before my `-` on the first line) and in fact found that multiple instances of `&nbsp;` per line can achieve the varied levels of indenting I was originally looking for.